# Is there a way to use MLS Api in php

Tags: api, rets, phrets, mls

I want to integrate the MLS in my website which is built in php.

Is there any services that could help me out. I want to integrate it in my custom plugin, so that whenever a user searches on my website it pulls the data using MLS api.

I have done some research and found the this link:- http://middleware.idxbroker.com/docs/api/1.0.4/mls.php#searchfields

Can be something that can help me out.

But there is no area where I can get accesskey from, which is required to use the api.

Answer (score 2):

You have two choices:

1. Build your own MLS system. You will have to register with your local real estate board to become a "technical provider", which will give you access to their RETS protocol, which allows you to download the latest MLS database. This isn't a searchable database: you will have to download all the listings to your own database, and must do so every 24 hours. There are all kinds of rules you must follow.

or

2. Pay a company which provides an API to access your local MLS database, such as Gavamedia (http://mlsidxapi.com) or Virtual Results (http://virtualresults.com/sites/). (I worked with the former last year, and they were quite helpful.) But the costs can be quite prohibitive.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is about MLS data in the U.S.A.? I can't provide a solution but help you explain in a nutshell what you need to know about MLS data.

There are about +900 MLS in the U.S. and their data is not publicly accessible. Hence the accesskey. To get the access key you'll have to be a registered agent/broker or application vendor with the MLS and you'll have to follow their rules either as an IDX or VOW consumer.

Your link is a IDX application vendor which provides normalized data from multiple MLS but you'll still need to be a registered user with your MLS.

Comment: I have been able to use it, I just want to use it in my custom plugin.

Comment: I don't understand. Do you still have a problem and need help or not?

Comment: @AdrianWorld I am looking for the best solution out there to build a real esate website without worpress plugin crap, I was wondering if you can give me suggestion please. I know I can use IDX provider or RETS can you advise me on how to proceed

Answer (score 0):

The link you provided:
http://middleware.idxbroker.com/docs/api/1.0.4/mls.php#searchfields
is from IDX Broker.

The API from IDX Broker will not pass the MLS properties data nor can you query the MLS data via that API. As for the access key those are provided in IDX Broker accounts. You can access a DEMO here here:
http://ptdemo.idxbroker.com/

IDX Broker does not require WordPress as all the listings and search results are on a custom subdomain and will work with just about any kind of site.